# SQL Server fails over while vmware virtual machine backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, vmware-esxi, failover, windows-cluster

Recently we moved clustered SQL Server 2017 running on Windows Server 2016 from physical to VMWare, since then everyday it started failing over at same time. No Error in SQL Server logs but Windows Event log shows SQL Server not being able to access data and log files before failover. On investigation we found that virtual machine backup was scheduled that time. Disabling the VM backup stopped the failover.

Comment: Lot of information is missing. What version of VMWare? What type of backup? What is the placement of the data files/transaction log/tempdb? What type of storage is used?

Comment: There are some VERY specific requirements for doing MS clustering in ESXi VMs - did you follow them? https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2147661

Comment: VMware ESXI version is 6.7. Incremental snapshot backups done by  Tivoli Storage Manager. data and log files on NAS ISCSI with MPIO while tempdb stored on separate disk.

Comment: What is the performance of the NAS? Is it using spinning disks? Same for tempdb.